# Is it possible to use the phrasal verb "stand out" as an adjective?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, phrasal-verbs

In the sentence "Tamara’s blue hair really makes her stand out", the phrasal verb "stand out" is used as an adjective, as I understood. In the following example from Oxford Learner's Dictionary, it's definitely a verb:

> The lettering stood out well against the dark background.

But in "Tamara’s blue hair really makes her stand out", all I see is that "make" is the verb, and "stand out" functions as an adjective because "she is stand out" is like "she is beautiful".

What am I missing and what's the function of "stand out" in "Tamara’s blue hair really makes her stand out"?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: ''stand out'' is *not* used as an adjective. Compare "Tamara’s blue hair really makes her stand out" and "Tamara’s blue hair really makes her beautiful".

Comment: You can rephrase it to: *Tamara stands out because of her blue hair.*

Comment: In that context, the function is the same. It's a verb, part of the structure, "make" + somebody + base form, as in, "*I **make my children eat** their vegetables.*"

Comment: @orhantorun That was my mistake. I must have intended to leave that comment on a different question (I closed many questions yesterday). I closed this one for lack of research, not because it was based on an error, and you have since added your research. Thanks!

Comment: to make, let, have, get, etc. (causative verbs) can be followed by a phrasal verb]. Make her sit down. Let him go out. Have him stand up. Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentence 'Tamara’s blue hair really makes her stand out' the phrasal verb 'stand out' is used as a verb, just like 'walk' in 'Tamara’s injured leg really makes her walk slowly'. She stands out because of her blue hair. She walks slowly because of her injured leg.

> stand out
> PHRASAL VERB   INTRANSITIVE
>
> to be easy to see or notice because of being different

[Stand out (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stand-out)

There is an adjective 'standout', usually written as one word, and mainly American informal, which means 'outstanding', or 'noticeably better'. You could use this in a sentence like 'I remember Tamara's standout blue hair'.

> standout
>
> ​ADJECTIVE  ​ONLY BEFORE NOUN
>
> ​AMERICAN ​INFORMAL
>
> noticeable because of being much better than anyone or anything else
>
> *a standout player/performance*

[Standout (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/standout_2)

Comment: Actually, it's not the whole expression "stand out" that is a verb, but just the word "stand". "Stand out" consists of the verb "stand" + the prep "out" as its complement.

Comment: I don't know why this had been downvoted.

Comment: @BillJ - so Macmillan is wrong? Also Cambridge? 'stand out — phrasal verb with stand'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Yes, they are, at least grammatically. "Stand out" forms a constituent, but at word level it’s a VP. Verb is a word category, like noun, adjective, etc., and it’s "stand" that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we have "Her hair stood out", but not ""Her hair stand outed".

Comment: @BillJ - I think the point is that the OP thought 'stand out' was an adjective. Possibly your point about unpacking phrasal verbs is a little abstruse, given the circumstances.

Comment: @BillJ Do phrasal verbs not exist, grammatically, or is "stand out" simply not an example of one?

Answer (score 0):

> *Tamara’s blue hair really makes her* [*stand out*].

No: "stand out" is not an adjective. It's a clause functioning as complement of "make", here a verb of causation. It consists of the verb "stand" followed by the preposition "out".

See here for the meaning: [link](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stand-out)

Comment: Doesn't a clause need to include a subject. Where is the subject in "stand out"?

Answer (score -1):

It’s not necessarily being used as an adjective; the meaning is actually preserved between your two examples. The phrasal verb “stand out” could be a verb in both cases that expresses essentially the same meaning. To help you understand the first sentence, let me offer some examples:

> Tamara’s golden dress made everyone’s jaws **drop**.
>
> The sprain in my ankle made me **fall** to my knees.
>
> Eating food makes me **feel** happy.
>
> Tamara’s blue hair really makes her **look** good.
>
> Puberty really made him **glow up**.

It is also possible to think of it as an adjective (though it’s not quite the same thing grammatically). Again, I’ll provide examples:

> Tamara’s blue hair made her **unique**.
>
> Her personality is what makes her **beautiful**.
>
> With that jacket, he looks very **grown up**.

Comment: I would avoid calling "stand out" a verb for the reason I gave in my comment to Michael Harvey.

Comment: @BillJ the author defines "stand out" as a PHRASAL verb and (admittedly) suggests it could be a verb. However, the *phrase* does consist of a verb, does it not? I have far larger reservations about the examples provided  and their idiomaticity.